# Get only visible columns when selecting a row in angular ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I want to select a row in angular-ui grid and copy the row to clip board.

This is my code:

```
  $scope.copySelection = function() {
    $scope.retainSelection = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.retainSelection));
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(input);
    input.value = JSON.stringify($scope.retainSelection);
    input.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    input.hidden = true;
    $scope.gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows();
  };
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/dcj7DUWHyA3u1bouxRhI?p=preview

However, I just want to copy the visible columns, but I am getting all the columns which are in the JSON. I dont want the hidden columns. How do I do that? Please help.

Comment: can u add a fiddle?

Comment: @MuhammedNeswine I have edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modulate the columns on the bases of selected columns/ visible columns. you can have a code like this -

```
 $scope.copySelection = function() {

    $scope.retainSelection =angular.copy($scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows());

    angular.forEach($scope.retainSelection,function(value,key){
       var columndef=angular.copy( $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs);
      for (var property in value) {
       if (!(value.hasOwnProperty(property) && columndef.filter(function(a){return a.name.split('.')[0]===property}).length>0 )) {
        delete value[property];
      }
    }

    });
    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.retainSelection));
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(input);
    input.value = JSON.stringify($scope.retainSelection);
    input.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    input.hidden = true;
    $scope.gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows();
  };
```

Find Updated Plunker  [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/f0mbvttjdH6q8ae7wUzF?p=preview)

Hope it will solve your problem!

Comment: Thanks Bro, was looking for the same :)